# Custom Matrix Field in Channel Form

Tags: matrix, safecracker, pixelandtonic

Implementing the solution found on [Bring Matrix Data Editing to the Front-End](http://themetaq.com/articles/bring-matrix-data-editing-to-the-front-end)
I've a matrix field that contains a [P&T Dropdown field type](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/fieldpack/fieldtypes/dropdown/tags.html)

```
<select name="role_level[row_new_0][col_id_46]">
{options:role_level}
<option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
{/options:role_level}
</select>
```

This doesn't work (no options output), the author of the post adviced to hard-code the options

```
<select name="level_matrix[row_new_0][col_id_46]">
<option value="">Choose Level</option>
<option value="Entry Level">Entry Level</option>
<option value="Experienced">Experienced</option>
<option value="Manager">Manager</option>
<option value="Executive">Executive</option>
</select>
```

How can i make the selected option remain "selected"? (will be doing this on many other fields)

Thanks

Comment: Just posting a note here to let onlookers know that i'm still working on this for the time being (stuartmcd69 your code seems working.) I’ll post an update back here once i have something to share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this in a recent project by making the actual field in the entry a text field - the entries were ever only going to be editable via front end so a dropdown/select was redundant. Then using Low Variables, created a dropdown/select that I can call in when required. I actually created a few for my needs but could work for you.

**Create form:**

```
<select name="scrim_type" >
    {exp:low_variables:options var="lv_scrim_type"}
    <option value="{lv_scrim_type:data}"{selected}>{lv_scrim_type:data_label}</option>
    {/exp:low_variables:options}
</select>
```

-- This saves the selected option to the text field on save.

**Edit Form**

```
{exp:channel:form entry_id="segment_3"}
    <select  name="scrim_type" >
        {exp:low_variables:options var="lv_scrim_type"}
        <option value="{lv_scrim_type:data}" {if lv_scrim_type:data == scrim_type}selected{/if}>{lv_scrim_type:data_label}</option>
        {/exp:low_variables:options}
    </select>
{/exp:channel:form}
```

The "if" statement uses the entries value for the text field `scrim_type` to 'select' the active option.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something but you have to set the option that the person has selected to selected="selected". This answer seems too easy though. What am I missing?

You were correct to hard code the values.