# Bring Matrix Data Editing to the Front-End using Channel Form

Tags: matrix, safecracker, pixelandtonic, fieldtype, field-pack

I am trying to create a form - FRONT END USER (channel form tag) - that uses a wizard (which is working) and in one panel it allows the user to fill in fields then duplicate the fieldset to add another set of criteria. I emailed Andris (P&T) and he sent me [this link](http://themetaq.com/articles/bring-matrix-data-editing-to-the-front-end) as a guide. I need some help, please.

```
<div class="fields" id="sortable">
            <div class="field"><!MATRIX FIELDS-->
            <input class="new_row_id" type="hidden" name="fundraising_organization[row_order][]" value="row_new_0">
                <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="fundraising name">Fundraising Organization Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fundraising_organization[row_new_0][10]" value="{fund_name}">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="fundraising address 1">Address 1</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fundraising_organization[row_new_0][11]" value="{fund_address_1}">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="fundraising address 2">Address 2</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fundraising_organization[row_new_0][12]" value="{fund_address_2}">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="fundraising city">City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fundraising_organization[row_new_0][13]" value="{fund_city}">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="fundraising state">State</label>
                     <select>
                        {options:fund_state}
                        <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_value}</option>
                        {/options:fund_state}
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="fundraising postal code">Postal Code</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fundraising_organization[row_new_0][15]" value="{fund_postal_code}">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="fundraising website">Website</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fundraising_organization[row_new_0][16]" value="{fund_website}">
                </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <input id="new" type="button" value="Add Another Organization">       
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
```

Should look like this (can't get Field Pack option to show either in above code):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a Field Pack Dropdown field, according to the author of the post on [Bring Matrix Data Editing to the Front-End](http://themetaq.com/articles/bring-matrix-data-editing-to-the-front-end)

> the reason it will not work is because the {options} tag pair for
>   ‘fund_state’ is looking for ‘root level’ options, and it (this native
>   usage) does not have a method for looking into a column of that field
>   since Matrix is third-party.

Got around this thanks to the answer to my question on this page: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/26144/48

Comment: How did you figure out the other part? I can't get any of the form to work. I need clarification on the field_name, which in my case looks to be fundraising_organization, and col_field_name_x, which is correct in my example as well. I will see about the options part according to the link you sent. For now none of it is working. Any suggestions? And thanks for answering.

Comment: Looks like you are using low variables as well. Is that in place of Field Pack or alongside Field Pack?

Comment: Yep, i'm using Low Variables alongside with PT Field Pack. Can you please explain what exactly isn't working with your form?

Comment: I am using Zoo Visitor for members. The purpose of the form is for users to be able to post a golf tournament using a form that will create and entry in a "tournament" channel that can be displayed in a member's dashboard or searched by any member.

Comment: Getting an error in sortable ... [Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
     containment: "parent"
    })')
 (anonymous function) (tournament-information, line 751)
 d (xx.xxxxx.xx, line 16)
 fireWith (xxx.xxxxx.xx, line 16)
 ready (xxx.xxxxx.xx, line 16)
 a (xxx.xxxxx.xx, line 16)